# Show updated data for selected rows after edit

Tags: reactjs, material-table

I have been using https://material-table.com/#/. I am selecting multiple rows in the table. Selecting rows will make the `Edit` action icon appear on the table-top. Then I use the `Edit` action to update the remote data for selected rows.

```
actions={[
   {
       icon: () => <Edit fontSize="default" />,
       tooltip: "Edit Selected",
       onClick: (event, rowData) => {
       handleBulkEdit(rowData);
       }
   },
          
]}
```

Clicking on `Edit` icon opens a dialog where I can modify some of the values of table fields. The dialog has a `Submit` button which updates the remote data in the backend using mongodb `updateMany` api call. The remote data is updated successfully for the selected rows in backend. But my problem is I don't know how to show the updated data for the selected rows in material-table after clicking on `Submit`

PS: I don't want to refresh the complete table, but instead when I click on Submit (in dialog) I should come back to the same selected rows with updated data.

Comment: `useState` didn't help?